# React application returning an empty div when deployed on github pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, github-pages

I have been working on deploying the website I am working on to github pages but It seems to return an empty div when deployed. when served with `npx serve build` it displays all information fine, and is displays on local host normally but just returns a blank div when deployed on github pages.

steps I took to deploy:

1. installed gh-pages
2. added "homepage" to package.json
3. npm run deploy

The package.json code is listed below incase there is an error in there

```
{
  "homepage": "https://jonlev03-hub.github.io/media-pilot/",
  "name": "media-pilot",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.2.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "gh-pages": "^4.0.0",
    "package.json": "^2.0.1",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "github-pages": "^0.1.0"
  }
}
```

and if you can't find any issues in that block of code all the code for the site is located inside my repository at github.com/jonlev03-hub/media-pilot .

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue relating to the use of  I hadn't specified a baseurl for the router to work with.